# discord.js [object Object]

Tags: sql, discord.js

First of yes i looked at other pages on hereabout object Object error, and of course they had no answers, so im trying to make a command that tells me how many people i have in my xp system (sql) and the number of people i would get it from would be from the id column in the xp table

so im getting [object Object] in my channel and no errors in console

this is the code im working with

```
module.exports.run = async(client, message, rows, con, result) => {
    const Discord = require("discord.js");
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var con = mysql.createConnection({

host: "remotemysql.com",

user: "oof",

port: "--",

password: "---",

database: "my peepee"

      });

      con.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM xp", function (err, result) {

        if (err) throw err;

        message.channel.send(result);

            }

            )};
```

Comment: Could you show us what's defining ``result``?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert an Object to a String, this will result in: `[object Object]`

Try to stringify the Object first like:

```
message.channel.send(require('util').inspect(result));
```

`util` is a node.js module thats included so no `npm i util` required